# how to make angular-map faster with lots of marker

Tags: angular

Hi i am developing a map with 1600 markers in angular7.
but it loads very slowly.

in my `.ts` file i have a function that read Lat and Longs from a json file:

```
private _populate() {
        this.httpClient.get('assets/latlongs.json').subscribe((res: any[]) => {
            res.forEach(y => {
                this._markers.push(y);
            }); });
        console.log('Markers : ');
        console.log(this._markers);
    }
```

i call `_populate()` in ngafterview:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        this._populate();
    }
```

my json file format (actually my json has 1600 LatLongs):

```
[
  {
    "latitude": 12.9407495,
    "longitude": 80.9471344
  },
  {
    "latitude": 12.9407495,
    "longitude": 80.9471344
  }
]
```

and finally my html:

```
<div style="height: 422px">
         <x-map #xmap [Options]="_options" [Box]="_box">
                <x-cluster-layer [GridSize]="150" [ClusteringEnabled]="true" [UseDynamicSizeMarkers]="true" [DynamicMarkerBaseSize]="18" [DynamicMarkerRanges]="_ranges" >
                    <x-map-marker *ngFor="let m of _markers; let i=index" [Latitude]="m.latitude" [Longitude]="m.longitude" [Title]="'User ' + i.toString()" [IconInfo]="_iconInfo">
                        <x-info-box [DisableAutoPan]="true" [Title]="'User ' + i.toString() + ' Details'" [Description]="'Hi, We can Load <strong>This User Info Here</strong>.'">
                            <x-info-box-action [Label]="'Click Me'" (ActionClicked)="_click(i)"></x-info-box-action>
                        </x-info-box>
                    </x-map-marker>
                </x-cluster-layer>
            </x-map>
        </div>
```

what can i do for load faster??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

for the typical usecase that you have I would suggest that you do not run *ngFor for all the coordinates at once rather you should do something like initially show the markers that are in the current viewport of the browser and as the user scroll you should dynamically create more markers so that all the 1600 markers are shown at once which will obviously slow down things. This is a typical usecase of lazy loading.